# Strategy to calculate Taylor series of compositions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, taylor-expansion

Suppose that $f,g$ are functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that $f(x_0) = \alpha $ and $g(f(x_0)) = \beta$, and both $f,g$ admit Taylor polynomials to arbitrary approximation at $x_0, f(x_0)$, respectively. **My question is about finding the Taylor approximations of $g \circ f$ by simply substituting the Taylor approximation of $f$ in that of $g$** - specifically, does this always work?

I know that, if $\alpha = 0$, we can do this (by an argument from Canuto and Tabacco's Mathematical Analysis 1, chapter 7.3). However, does the above strategy work regardless of what $\alpha, \beta$ might be? If not, what are the conditions on $\alpha, \beta$, and what do we do when the above doesn't work (aside from directly computing derivatives of the composition w/ Faa di Bruno's formula)?

Comment: This is surely a duplicate. This is more or less about the proof $gf$ is analytic

Comment: Yes, it is the same as Faa do Bruno.

Comment: @AShrike Could you elaborate on why that might be the case? I haven't seen much of complex analysis yet, so for me, analyticity is merely being admitting a local power series approximation. Why should the above question boil down to the product admitting such an approximation?

Comment: Also it's worth noting that $\alpha=0$ is easy to reduce to "without loss of generality" just by taking translations. If you've already seen an argument for this, the argument will generalise